# aggregation result from SQL view to gridview

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have this View from multi tables

account_name.......bonus..........value

customer1............A............14000

customer1............B............500

customer1............C............14500

customer2............A............20000

customer2............B............200

customer2............C............20200

http://im33.gulfup.com/Nt0mM.png

how can i retrieval this view and show it on GridView this View using LINQ

...................A.........B..........C

customer1.......14000.......500.......14500

customer2.......20000.......200.......20200

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT account_name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN bonus = 'A' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS A,
SUM(CASE WHEN bonus = 'B' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS B,
SUM(CASE WHEN bonus = 'C' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM YouView
GROUP BY account_name
```

Comment: If the SQL enables better to do on SQL

Comment: thankx , but how can I make it if I have more than ( A , B , C) bonus. I mean I have table of bonus which its columns: bonus , value

Comment: Then you can look in the direction of PIVOT, UNPIVOT

Comment: thank you , this article may solved my problem ,, 
"""Pivots with Dynamic Columns """

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using Pivots with dynamic as realnumber3012 recommend...

the demonstrate of the table and the result on this link

[image]

---

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + bounse_name+ ']','[' + bounse_name + ']')
FROM    dbo.tbl_bounse
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT account_name , '+ @cols +'
FROM
(SELECT     tbl_account.account_name, tbl_account.account_career,     
            tbl_bounse.bounse_name, tbl_detail.detail_value
FROM         tbl_account INNER JOIN
tbl_detail ON tbl_account.account_id = tbl_detail.detail_accound_id 
INNER JOIN
tbl_bounse ON tbl_detail.detail_bounce_id = tbl_bounse.bounse_id                     
                   )  p
PIVOT
(
MAX([detail_value])
FOR bounse_name IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt;'

EXECUTE(@query)
```